# Can't see Background image but its not hidden (blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling, image

I was modelling something of this background image and I hid the background image to work on the feet of the model and when I tried to u hide I couldn't see it at all but it said it was showing.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: are you in 2.7? So you mean you were using an HDRI or a Background image as a blueprint? Your question is too vague...

Comment: Make sure your view is orthographic, background images are only visible in ortho. (Numpad5 to switch between perspective and orthographic)